# file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/tmp/log.htm) is not within the allowed path(s)

Tags: php, codeigniter, dompdf

I am building pdf generating an app using CodeIgniter and DOMPDF. Its working fine in my localhost but when I move these files to the server it gives me the following error. Please, how can I resolve this issue?

```
Severity: Warning

Message: file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/tmp/log.htm) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/admin/web/fryapps.com/public_html:/home/admin/tmp)

Filename: src/Dompdf.php

Line Number: 714

Backtrace:

File: /home/admin/web/fryapps.com/public_html/application/libraries/dompdf/src/Dompdf.php
Line: 714
Function: file_exists

File: /home/admin/web/fryapps.com/public_html/application/controllers/Createpdf.php
Line: 31
Function: render
```

path of image error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfy6T.jpg

this is my code:

```
$htmlcontent= $this->load->view('admin/test',$data,true);              
$this->pdf->loadHtml($htmlcontent);
$this->pdf->render();
$this->pdf->stream("report.pdf",array("Attachment=>0"));
```

anyone, please help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: provide the absolute path /home/admin/tmp/<filename>

Comment: @kuh-chan Where I have to edit this?

Comment: How to solve this issue?

Comment: when you look into the code of Dompdf you'll see that it'll create a `logOutputFile`. You can set it in the options array

Comment: $this->setLogOutputFile($this->getTempDir() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "log.htm");   this one?

Comment: what I need to change in this line?? could you please help me?

Comment: more `$this->pdf->set_option('logOutputFile', $this->getTempDir() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'log.htm');` wait... why am I reading the docs for you?

Answer (score 1):

create folder "/home/admin/web/example.com/tmp"

Use it

```
$this->pdf->set_options('tempDir','/home/admin/web/example.com/tmp');
```

OR

Class use `sys_get_temp_dir();`

Set it in VirtualHost for example.com

```
php_admin_value sys_temp_dir "/home/admin/web/example.com/tmp"
```

Comment: my domain is fryapps.com so I need to create tmp folder in the root directory? and  in which file should i set this $this->pdf->set('tempDir','/home/admin/web/example.com/tmp');

Comment: Call to undefined method Pdf::set()

Comment: there is exist https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/blob/master/src/Options.php it inner class, Use set_options https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/blob/master/src/Dompdf.php

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this by upgrading php version of cpanel.